# AngularJS Routing not working (not even detecting)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I used this code as localhost so that's not the problem.

Used pastebin because this editor was breaking my code for about 10 minutes...

main.js -> http://pastebin.com/gePdrETv

index.html -> http://pastebin.com/ehDCyqN6

route2.html -> http://pastebin.com/4s2gtY4j

route1.html -> http://pastebin.com/RDAGQKPv

I am trying to change the view in index.html in ng-view so that I could see different views (/ change views). But it's not working at all (not even a data bind is working, just showing me the {{ message }})

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include the following JS as well.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.js

This is for Angular 1.4.9.

The module `ngRoute` is defined in this separate JS file, so your Angular application can't even bootstrap I think.

Check your console output, I think you'll see an `$injector:modulerr` there.
See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr) which specifically mentions `ngRoute`.

Comment: I am getting the error you said, also I implemented the `angular-route.js` now but still one problem is left being that Angular isn't even detecting that it's an Angular app (data binds are shown as `{{ message }}` and not as the data behind it). But I think this has something to do with my folder structure so this should be the solution.